# gulp-order node module with merged streams

Tags: node.js, angularjs, concatenation, gulp, node-modules

I'm using the gulp-order module along with the event-streams module and gulp-concat to concatenate javascript files into a single dest file.  The gulp-order plugin has worked great for me in other projects where I wanted to concatenate files from the stream in a distinct order.  For some reason in this project it is not working properly, and the files in the public/angular/config directory are dispersed amongst the files I specify to concatenate last in the public/js directory.  I think this may have something to do with specifying multiply sources ie. the angular and js directories.  I tried merging the streams with the event-streams module with no luck, whereas when I first began I specified the multiple sources by passing an array to the gulp.src function

```
gulp.src(['./public/angular/**/*.js', './public/js/*.js'])
```

Below is the code I'm using now.  The piping and concatenation are working fine but the order is not following the specification:

```
var gulp         = require('gulp');
var concat       = require('gulp-concat');
var notify       = require('gulp-notify');
var handleErrors = require('../util/handleErrors');
var jshint       = require('gulp-jshint');
var ngmin        = require('gulp-ngmin');
var order        = require('gulp-order');
var es           = require('event-stream');

function getStream(streamPath) {
  return gulp.src(streamPath);
};

gulp.task('scripts', function() {
    return es.merge(getStream('./public/angular/**/*.js'),getStream('./public/js/*.js'))
        .pipe(order([
          './public/angular/config/*.js',
          './public/angular/services/**/*.js',
          './public/angular/modules/**/*.js',
          './public/angular/primitives/**/*.js',
          './public/js/**/*.js'
        ]))
        .pipe(concat('app.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./public/build/js'))
        .on('error', handleErrors);
});
```

Comment: Same issue and it was working yesterday and now it is not.

Comment: Hey @Nick I scrapped the order module and started using streamqueue.  Works great, you can check it on my github https://github.com/dtothefp/gulp-angular-foundation/blob/master/gulp/tasks/scripts.js

Comment: turns out I am a dummus, I changed the file names.. no wonder they were out of order!!! BTW you can do this with order or just use gulp.src([file1,file2,file3*]) . I do not think streamqueue is necessary.

Answer (score 12):

I had this same issue, and I used `gulp-print` to see the filenames in my stream, but they were correct. I found out that I needed to add the `base` option to `gulp-order`, then all worked well.

```
gulp.src(['myFiles/*', 'myOtherFiles/*'])
   .pipe(order([
      'myOtherFiles/lib1.js',
      'myFiles/lib2.js'
   ], {base: '.'});
```

<del>Helpful article: http://martinwolf.org/2014/08/12/force-a-concatenation-order-with-gulp-js/</del>

**UPDATE:** new link to blog article: https://martinwolf.org/blog/2014/08/force-a-concatenation-order-with-gulp-js

Comment: This fixed it for me too. It seems odd that piping direct from `gulp.src` would require this base option.