# Gulp order - how to concatenate or add a certain javascript file last?

Tags: javascript, gulp, bower

I am using gulp with bower and a number of other scripts with the following directory structure:

```
.
|- bower_components
|---- various_packages
|- js
|---- functions.js (my custom javascript)
|---- test_example_vendor_item.js
```

My gulp is using [main-bower-files](https://github.com/ck86/main-bower-files) to grab the bowser files, and then concatenates my other js files.

**The main problem is that within the js folder itself, I need `functions.js` to be concatenated after `test_example_vendor_item.js`.**

Apart from simply renaming `functions.js` to `zzz_functions.js`, or all the other files to `zzz_vendor.example.js`, is there a way to ensure that `functions.js` is concatenated last?

I'm trying to use [gulp-order](https://github.com/sirlantis/gulp-order) to no avail, evidently as the initial wildcard will accept all in its original order:

```
gulp.task('js', function() {
  var jsFiles = ['js/*'];
  gulp.src(plugins.mainBowerFiles().concat(jsFiles))
      .pipe(plugins.filter('*.js'))
      .pipe(plugins.order([
        '*',
        'functions.js'
      ]))
      .pipe(plugins.concat('main.js'))
      .pipe(plugins.uglify())
      .pipe(gulp.dest(dest + 'js'))
});
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [gulp concat scripts in order?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21961142/gulp-concat-scripts-in-order)

Answer (score 1):

Sure . . .

```
 gulp.task('js', function() {
   var jsFiles = ['js/*'];
   gulp.src(plugins.mainBowerFiles().concat(jsFiles))
    .pipe(plugins.filter('*.js'))
    .pipe(plugins.order([
      '!(functions.js)*',
      'functions.js'
    ]))
    .pipe(plugins.concat('main.js'))
    .pipe(plugins.uglify())
    .pipe(gulp.dest(dest + 'js'))
});
```

The idea is to select all js files except for functions.js, and then to select functions.js.

Answer (score 0):

*try this:

```
.pipe(plugins.order([
  '!(functions.js)*',
  'functions.js'
]))
```

Comment: Could you give a complete example?