# Concatenate javascript and css in order

Tags: javascript, jquery, gulp

I have several task to concatenate css and javascript together, here is an example:

```
gulp.task('javascript', function() {
  return gulp.src([
    libPath + 'jquery-2.1.4.min.js',
    libPath + '*.js',
    jsPath + 'app.js'
  ])
  .pipe(concat('app.min.js'))
  .pipe(uglify())
  .pipe(gulp.dest(jsPath))
});
```

Ideally (in this example) I would like following order `jQuery -> libraries -> app.js` and so far, using code above it seems to work. However I conducted a little research and people seem to be using plugins like [gulp-order](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-order) or [require streamqueue ..](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23507836/911930) method instead of require `gulp.src`, thus I wanted to make sure that these are needed, or does gulp take care of that now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For what I saw in the links, those plugins are used to order the stream of multiple files, like: `gulp.src(["js/*.js"])`, but you are explicitly declaring the order, so it works.

Comment: I just noticed that jQuery is concatenated twice with my approach, is there a way to work around it, yet still keep it first in order?

Comment: I'm sorry I didn't saw your ` libPath + '*.js' `, I think that's why you would use gulp-order, that way you can source everything from each path, and then give it the order you like, exactly as in your example, otherwise you would have to explicitly declare every file.