# gulp-concat: how to ensure a file is concatenated last?

Tags: javascript, gulp, gulp-concat

```
gulp.task('scripts', function() {
  return gulp.src(['!dev/js/vendor-list.js', 'dev/js/**/*.js'])
    .pipe(concat('all.min.js'))
    .pipe(gulp.dest('public'));
});
```

The above code is a sample of my gulp task using `gulp-concat`. Somewhere in the pile is my `app.js` file which I would like concatenated  last. Is there a way to do it without having to list all the sub-folders in order? All other files are order agnostic. My `app.js` is the only one order sensitive that I need concatenated last. I thought about doing two streams in a single task and then merging the output, but I was hoping for a simpler solution. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this (from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21961142/gulp-concat-scripts-in-order)):

```
[
  '!dev/js/vendor-list.js', // can probably be included in the statement below.
  '/dev/js/!(app)*.js', // all files that end in .js EXCEPT app*.js
  '/dev/js/app.js', // this should be concatenated last
]
```