# Gulp - concat files in order

Tags: javascript, html, gulp, concatenation

Why Gulp is doing wrong (or its ok, but i need something else) order in concating files?

Here is image for example (on the left, my scripts order and on the right concated file) :

[image]

Notificator.js should be on first place...

Folder notificator is in /components/notificator. Here is my gulpfile.js:

```
gulp.src('./htdocs/js/components/**/*.js')
        .pipe(concat('components.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./htdocs/dist/js/')),
```

Comment: How is gulp supposed to know the order you want? Do you just expect the files to be concatenated in alphabetical order or something more complicated?

Comment: Same order as in my files order :)

Comment: How exactly am I or is anyone else supposed to know how your files are ordered? Asciibetical? Ignore the extension? Case-sensitive? Unless you specify exactly how the files should be ordered this question is not useful.

Comment: Exacly as is in image i posted. Alphabetically.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [gulp concat scripts in order?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21961142/gulp-concat-scripts-in-order)

Answer (score 2):

You can pass in a array as source like this,

```
gulp.src(['PATHTOFILE', 'PATHTOFILE'])
        .pipe(concat('components.js'))
        .pipe(gulp.dest('./htdocs/dist/js/'))
```

or you can use something called [gulp-useref](https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-useref), that basically it runs through your decalare in the html and concat them in that order.

Comment: For me that that is the prefered way to do it, all in one place. There is an alternative though, a gulp package, gulp-useref, https://www.npmjs.com/package/gulp-useref @Sko